# Sort ng-repeat tags by custom list?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter, angularjs-orderby

My ng-repeat show big data , and after groupBy it divides in 5 divs

```
<div ng-repeat=" (key, value) in gamesList | groupBy: 'id' ">...</div>
```

ID value is

```
{ '1' , '2' , '3' , '4' , '5' }
```

and in result it orders from min to max .

How can I order it with my custom rule, like this:

```
{'5' , '2' , '4' , '1' , '3' }
```

Comment: what is the logic for custom rule

Comment: `{ '1' , '2' , '3' , '4' , '5' }` - what kind of structure is that?

Comment: you can create your own custom filter by your logic and use that.

Comment: You can use a `sort()` function to achieve your goal.

Comment: @Sajeetharan , its just by default

Comment: @MohitSaxena , yes , but how i can do that . no idea

Comment: @Sajeetharan its just custom list order , has not some logical statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Can sort your data using `sort()` function instead of using filter.
You have to define your rule like this :

```
var myRule = {'5':1,'2':2,'4':3,'1':4,'3':5}
```

And then you have to apply your custom rule over your data.

```
scope.gameList=scope.gameList.sort(function(a,b){
  return myRule[a.id]>myRule[b.id];
});
```

You can do this by using custom filter as follows :

```
myApp.filter('myFilter', function() {
 return function(input) {
   var output;
   var myRule = {'5':1,'2':2,'4':3,'1':4,'3':5};

   output = input.sort(function(a, b) {  
    return myRule[a.id]>myRule[b.id];
   });

   return output;
  }
});
```

And You can apply your custom filter like this :

```
<div ng-repeat="d in data | myFilter">
```

[Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/ArOKf4q45zjSJRqGVymL?p=preview) is an example on plunker.
Hope this would help you!

Comment: Doesnt help , for what is this myRule = {'5':1,'2':2,'4':3,'1':4,'3':5} ? Its my orderList ?

Comment: You want to sort data by custom rule, So there must be a criteria. I just set a rule on ids. You can have different criteria. I assume that I have 5 records with ids 1 to 5 and myRule says that id my id=5 that record should be first record and so on.

Comment: If there is way use it like | orderBy: myRule ?